# The meaning and usage of the expression "никуда не денешь"

Tags: выражения

> Есть ощущение суетности, которое потом **никуда не денешь**. Хотя, конечно, все, что угодно, — за ваши деньги.

I'm not sure if this phrase qualifies as an idiom, but does it mean something like "you/one cannot deny its presence" or "there's no getting around that fact"?

Comment: a sense of vanity which will stick with you/you'll be burdened with afterwards (as an aftertaste)

Answer (score 1):

This means "the sense of vanity one can't get rid of".

Usually this is phrased as *ощущение суетности, от которого никуда не денешься* "the sense of vanity you can't get away from", and it might even convey slightly different connotation ("remove the feeling" vs. "walk away from the feeling"), however, both of those just mean something which is gonna stay whether you want it or not.

Answer (score 0):

It is an idiom and like any of them has no direct translation. And, like any of them, has many subtle shades of meaning depending on the contect.
Both of your guesses are correct.
There are a few variations on this idiom. I cannot recall many, but here is the one:
Никуда не денешься
Meaning you ain’t gonna have no options.
Example, когда зима придет, ты никуда не денешься, придешь ко мне с поклоном.
And here is one more:
А куда ты денешься?
Most of the time you hear this idiom in  dialogues:
-я не хочу иметь никаких дел с тобой.
-А куда ты денешься? Ты будешь делать как я сказал.

One more word of comment. You can use ВЫ refering to a group of people, but it is NEVER used in adressing a peron in honorofic sencr of the word ВЫ (singular). Examples you brought are neutral, example I brought are used in situations of very tough speaking.

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I don't consider "деться от чего-то" or "деть что-то куда-то" an idiom. "Деться" means "cкрыться", "спрятаться", "исчезнуть", and the word is just informal:

> Куда делся мой ключ? (where is my key? (the key has disappeared, I
>   can't find it!))
>
> Куда делся твой друг? (where did your friend go? (he's gone, I don't see him anywhere))

"Деть что-то куда" means "запрятать", "поместить", "истратить", and just like "деться", which is reflexive, the word is informal.

If you can't *деться* *от* some feeling/thought, or if you can't *деть* the feeling/thought *никуда*, then you can't shake it off:

> Я не могу никуда деться от собственных мыслей / я не могу их никуда деть. (the thoughts are too disturbing)
>
> Зачем ты его пригласил? Теперь от него никуда не деться / теперь его никуда не денешь. (it's no longer about a feeling or thought, of course, but about a person, who is hard to get rid of)

Comment: @Баян Купи-ка this is exactly what I say, “I don’t consider...an idiom.”

Comment: oops, sorry, seems to be my cross eye